# Simple login system for PhoneGap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, authentication

I'm trying to build a simple login system for my PhoneGap app. I have a form where user gives a username and if there is a matching username in the MYSQL the user is redirected to another page. Else an alert is shown. The code works just fine on firefox and chrome, but when I try to use it on Safari or on the PhoneGap app it doesn't seem to work. What could be the reason?

HTML

```
    <form id="login-form" rel="external" data-ajax="false" >

    <label for="number">Number:</label> 
    <br>
    <input type='tel' name="number" id="number" data-corners="false" data-theme="d"/>
    <br>

    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <br>

    <input name="username" id="username" data-corners="false" data-theme="d"/>
    <br>

<input type="submit" value="OK" data-theme="b" data-corners="false" />
</form>
```

JS

```
 $(function() {    
     $('#login-form').submit(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

         $.post(serviceURL +'login.php', { 
             kayttaja: $('[name="username"]').val(), 
         }).success(function(data) { 
             if (data.status == 'ok') {
                 var input = document.getElementById("number");
                 var user = document.getElementById("username");
                localStorage.setItem("number", input.value);
                localStorage.setItem("username", user.value);
                 window.location.pathname = data.redirect;
             } else {
                 alert(data.message);
             }
         })
     })
})
```

Comment: which version of phonegap are you using?? If its cordova then check whether you have included the server in `<access origin=''>` list

Comment: I'm using cordova, and i have set `<access origin=".*"/> `

Answer (score 2):

you can follow these steps for creating simple login system using phonegap / apache cordova

- Create **JSON based Web Service** for Authentication Purpose
- Use JQuery / Angular JS for Connect with Web Service using Ajax method
- If authentication success, redirect page using javascript `window.location.href="home.html"`
- use **localStorage** for Storing auth values

I got this information from https://codesundar.com/phonegap-login-system-using-php-mysql/

Comment: Updated broken link